# How to redirect view with a variable laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I have encrypted url.If I do not encrypted then all things works fine.Now I want encrypted url and send `$applicantData` variable to the view (confirmation blade).But if i add encryption then it url changes perfectly but i can not send `$applicantData` variable to view that's i am getting error.How can i solve this problem? I am using laravel 5.2.

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'career'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'careerHome' , 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@index']);
    Route::get('apply', ['as' => 'addApplicant', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@create']);
    Route::post('save', ['as' => 'saveApplicant', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@store']);
    Route::get('confirmation/{id}', ['as' => 'confirmationMsg', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@show']);
});
```

**ApplicantController:**

```
$id = $applicant->id;
$applicantData = Applicant::whereId($id)->first();
\Session::flash('flash_message','Application has been successfully submitted.');
return redirect()->to('career/confirmation/'.encrypt($id))->withErrors(compact("applicantData"));
```

Comment: Did you `decrypt($id)` in your `ApplicantController -> public function show($id) { decrypt($id); }`?

Comment: @RobinDirksen No.I do not decrypted in ApplicantController .

Answer (score 1):

Use `Redirect::to` for redirect, `withInput()->withErrors(['msg' => "some error happens"]);` like this way:

```
return Redirect::to('career/confirmation/'.encrypt($id))->withInput()->withErrors(compact("applicantData"));
```

and in your blade show the error like this:

```
      <ul class="errors">
@foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
@endforeach
      </ul>
```

Comment: Its showing error `Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\NoticeBoard\resources\views\applicant\confirmation.blade.php)`

Comment: var_dump(compact("applicantData"))

Comment: Its returns applicantData value of array.But how can i show these data in other blade(confirmation blade)?

Comment: Is it a multi array? If this trans it to one dimmension array.

Comment: OK it's a array transed form an object with protected and public and static members. Are you want to show all that info in you page. Ror some value of $message in the blade is array,  so you get that error.

Comment: if that you can prepare the into to a new one dimmension array, then pass it to the blade. or yor can access it by $message[$k1][$k2].... But I recoment the first one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131680/discussion-between-kris-roofe-and-chonchol-mahmud).